# What is the general solution to the equation $\sin x + \sqrt{3}\cos x = \sqrt2$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the general solution to the equation

$$\sin(x) + \sqrt3\cos(x)=\sqrt2$$

So I went ahead and divided by $2$, thus getting the form

$$\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{6})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$$

Thus the general solution to this would be $$x =  2n\pi \pm\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Which simplifies out to be,

$$x = 2n\pi +\frac{5\pi}{12}$$ $$ x = 2n\pi -\frac{\pi}{12}$$

But the answer doesn't have the 2nd solution as a solution to the given equation. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: Your answer seems to be  the correct one. For example $x=-\frac {\pi} {12}$ does satisfy the given equation.

Comment: You solution is correct. May be they skip the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570010/what-is-the-general-solution-to-the-equation-sin-x-sqrt3-cos-x-sqrt2/3570014#comment7340586_3570010) indicates, you haven't done anything wrong that I can see.  You can quite easily very that $x = 2n\pi - \frac{\pi}{12}$ is a solution (coming from using $\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ on the right), as well as the first one you specify of $x = 2n\pi + \frac{5\pi}{12}$ (coming from using $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ on the right). Thus, it seems the answer has an oversight.

Comment: Yes I guess so, it's a multiple choice question and both were given as options and only one was given correct, hence my confusion, I'm really just starting out with this topic

Comment: @Techie5879 Unless there's some stated restriction on what $x$ could be, they are both valid options, so it seems the multiple-choice test has a mistake in it.

Comment: Got it. And no, there are no restrictions